# Filter rows for specific columns in R

Tags: r, filter

I need to filter rows if some of the variables have missing values. Here is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 v1 = c(5,6,7,8,1),
                 v2 = c(5,9,34,2,1),
                 a1 = c(1,NA,NA,2,3),
                 a2 = c(NA,1,NA,8,9))

> df
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
4  4  8  2  2  8
5  5  1  1  3  9
```

From columns 4 and 5, if there is any missingness, I need to filter them. How can I code by specifying the column number (4th column) to the end of the columns? Because I have multiple and differentiating in the number of columns for different datasets.

How can I get this filtered dataset below?

```
> df1
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Base R Approach

---

#### Approach 1

Using `complete.cases`

```
df[!complete.cases(df[, 4:ncol(df)]),]
```

#### Approach 2

Using `apply` function

```
df[apply(df[, 4:ncol(df)], 1, FUN = function(x) any(is.na(x))), ]
```

#### Approach 3

Using `data.table` library (Faster Approach)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[!complete.cases(df[, 4:ncol(df)])]
```

---

**Dataset used**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 v1 = c(5,6,7,8,1),
                 v2 = c(5,9,34,2,1),
                 a1 = c(1,NA,NA,2,3),
                 a2 = c(NA,1,NA,8,9))
```

Answer (score 2):

in base R you could do:

```
df[!complete.cases(df[4:ncol(df)]),]
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA

subset(df, !complete.cases(df[4:ncol(df)]))
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `base` option:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[, 4:ncol(df)])) > 0, ]
```

And a faster and less verbose `any(is.na(x))` alternative:

```
df[apply(df[, 4:ncol(df)], 1, anyNA), ]
```

Output:

```
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

My contribution is this simple line of code from dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   v1 = c(5,6,7,8,1),
                   v2 = c(5,9,34,2,1),
                   a1 = c(1,NA,NA,2,3),
                   a2 = c(NA,1,NA,8,9))
                   
    new_df <- df %>% 
    filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))

print(new_df)

id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if_any` in `filter` - specify the column index range (`:`) from 4 to `last_col()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(4:last_col(), is.na))
  id v1 v2 a1 a2
1  1  5  5  1 NA
2  2  6  9 NA  1
3  3  7 34 NA NA
```